# How to refresh display on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, display

So does Ubuntu 12.04 have the windows equivalent to the "connect to projector" key functionality. I have a hardware problem on my laptop where the lcd screen goes white (and I know at some point I have to change the cables or maybe the screen). But on windows I can simply press the "connect to projector" key (the F1 key in my case) and I get back the display and it works 9/10 times. Is there a way to do something similar in Ubuntu 12.04? Plus I cant do anything complicated like opening up terminal or any application, because I dont have the display. So it has to be 1 or 2 keystrokes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Ubuntu does not have a "connect to projector" key.

However,   I would like to draw your attention to the `xrandr` command and the "keyboard shortcuts" in "settings". These two would be the main starting point to cobble something together that could function like a "connect to projector" key.